# .gitignore does not take into account the .classpath file

Tags: java, eclipse, git

There is `/android` directory where is set up `android` project(by `eclipse`) which `tree -a` looks like:

```
.
├── AndroidManifest.xml
├── assets
├── bin
│   ├── 
├── .classpath
├── gen
│   ├── 
├── .gitignore
├── ic_launcher-web.png
├── libs
│   └── 
├── lint.xml
├── proguard-project.txt
├── .project
├── project.properties
├── res
│   ├── 
├── .settings
│   ├── 
└── src
    └──
```

also in this folder `.gitignore` is set as:

```
# generated files
bin/
gen/

# Eclipse project files
.classpath
.project
```

The issue is that `git` does not take into account it. Exampl: every time the `.classpath` from above directory get modified it is marked under `git` as a modified.

There is one .gitignore over the /android but it is commited as empty.

Regards

Comment: `.gitignore` is for ignoring *new* files, not modifications to *already tracked* files. See http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Comment: That's logical.. any idea how to effectively clean repository from  unwanted files/directories ?

Comment: issue `git rm --cached .classpath` first.

Comment: @Kuba That sounds like an entirely different question, but have a look at `git clean`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik voilà! Simply we need to remove that file -> commit -> add again. It works. Thanks

Comment: Just note that all others will have their `.classpath` deleted when they pull. This could be a major concern. BTW if you used the `--cached` option, the file would not have been removed from the filesystem, just from the index.